# MFMailComposeViewController can be without presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone

Apple provides the code to use MFMailComposeViewController.but it uses

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[controller setSubject:@"In app email..."];

[controller setMessageBody:@"...a tutorial from mobileorchard.com" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

}
by default it uses bottom  UP transition.suppose if i want to use following, it gives wrong
ouput.**can i use other add subview like that instead of presentModalViewController**

```
{

    UIViewAnimationTransition  trans =  UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight;

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:trans forView: [self view] cache: YES];
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**it works correctly for other view controller,but it did not work in MFMailComposeViewController any help please?**

hi i have done like this,but current view controller  flips, and then composer comes from
bottom..?will you help?
- (IBAction)clickedMailButton:(id)sender

```
{

  if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{ 

      MFMailComposeViewController *mcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    //[mcontroller setSubject:@"My Pocket Schedule"];
    [mcontroller setTitle:@"New Message"];
    [mcontroller setMessageBody:@"Check out My Pocket Schedule in the iTune Store" isHTML:NO];
    mcontroller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    UIViewAnimationTransition  trans =  UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight;
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:trans forView: [self view] cache: YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mcontroller animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [mcontroller release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

[presentModalViewController:withTransition:](http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/06/30s-presentmodalviewcontrollerwithtrans.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `modalTransitionStyle` property:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mcontroller setTitle:@"..."];
[mcontroller setMessageBody:@"..." isHTML:NO];
mcontroller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
mcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:mcontroller animated:YES];
[mcontroller release];
```

Comment: it did not work in MFMailComposer's presentModalViewController..
have u checked pls?

Comment: pls check my code which is in last ( i have edited my question)...
i tried... will you help please?

Comment: Even in your edited sample code, you have not done what I suggested. I have edited my answer to give a little more context.